# Strategies for optimizing the performance of IO intesive jobs on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I wrote a script that analyzes a lot of files on an AWS cluster.

Running it on the cloud seems to be slower than I expected - the filesystem is shared via NFS, so the round-trip through the network seems to be the limiting step here. Bottom line - the processing power of the cluster is limited by the speed of the internal network which is considerably slower than the speed of the SSD the data is located in.

How would you optimize the cluster so that IO intensive jobs will run efficiently?

Comment: No.. The files are stored on an EBS volume that is shared via NFS to all the nodes in the cluster

Comment: You need to replace your home made NFS to the new Amazon EFS... that is specially designed to the type of work that you want to execute, as well for Big Data jobs, etc... The only "but" is that EFS is only in Preview Stage https://aws.amazon.com/efs/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do given the circumstances.
Obviously the speed of the NFS itself is the drawback.

Consider:

1. Chunking - grab only pieces of the files required to do as much as possible
2. Copying locally - create a locking mechanism and copy the file in full locally, process, push back. This can require a lot of work (what if the worker gives up and doesnt clear the lock)
3. Optimize the NFS share - increase IO throughput by clustering the NFS, raiding it, etc.

With a remote FS you want to limit the amount of back and forth. You can be creative, but creative can be a problem in itself.

Comment: Other suggestions: look at the new EFS product (as a way to reduce any network latency issues), if sticking with EBS, try raid as you mentioned, or switch to (non PIOPS) SSD that gives you faster speed depending on the size of the disks.